# Flutter - can't access to previous PaintingContext in RenderObject paint function

Tags: flutter

I have a `LeafRenderObjectWidget` and want to update my view according to the new widget parameters. for example, I have drawn a line and wish to update the line using scale and don't want to paint it again on the next build.
the problem is in the `paint` function of RenderObject I have access to `PaintingContext` but it is not the previous one. so I can't use `context.canvas.save()` and restore it again in the paint function.

Comment: `Canvas.save()` method is used for "saving" current clip and transformation matrix - if you don't change them there is no need to call it

Answer (score 0):

When creating RenderObjects from scratch it's easy to get carried away, but my advice is to not fear repainting. When you call methods on a canvas all it's doing is adding commands to a list that eventually get sent to the raster thread, no actual rendering work is being done here.

It sounds like you are confused on the purpose of `canvas.save` and `canvas.restore`. These methods do not save what you painted to the canvas, they only touch the paint transform set by scale, skew, transform and translate.