# How to update shape in RenderObjcet instead of painting from scratch

Tags: flutter

I have a custom LeafRenderObjectWidget that receives the count of rectangles as an input parameter and draws the rectangles.

every time that `paint` function calls it gives a new PaintingContext so I can't save the already drawn rectangles, and I have to draw them again.

I wish I could save the previously drawn rectangles and only draw the new one.
because of the performance issues, I need to update my canvas instead of painting from scratch.

in this provided example the paint function only draws the latest rectangle.

```dart
class MyCustomShape extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  final int count;

  const MyCustomShape({Key? key, required this.count}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return MyCustomShapeRenderObject(count);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, covariant RenderObject renderObject) {
    MyCustomShapeRenderObject myCustomShapeRenderObject =
        renderObject as MyCustomShapeRenderObject;
    myCustomShapeRenderObject.count = count;
  }
}

class MyCustomShapeRenderObject extends RenderBox {
  late int _count;

  MyCustomShapeRenderObject(int count) {
    _count = count;
  }

  bool initialPaint = true;
  bool needTick = false;
  bool newCandle = false;
  bool needTransform = false;
  bool needHorizontalcount = false;
  bool needVerticalcount = false;
  bool needColor = false;

  set count(int value) {
    if (_count == value) {
      return;
    }
    _count = value;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  /// set size as large as possible
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    size = Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(100 * _count.toDouble() , 0),
        Offset(100 * _count.toDouble(), 100),
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.red
          ..strokeWidth = 10);
  }
}
```

also, I have tried to save the canvas using `context.canvas.save()` and restore it in the next `paint` run. but because the PaintingContext object is not the same. it can't restore the previously painted shapes.

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889], locale en-US)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.8)
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.70.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: `Canvas.save()` method is used for "saving" current clip and transformation matrix - if you don't change them there is no need to call it - in other words: `save` method has nothing to do with previously drawn stuff

Comment: maybe your performance issues come from the `Canvas.drawLine`, tried `Canvas.drawRect`?

Comment: You don't just simply draw next and another every time count updates.
You have to either Stack multiple renderbox on each other, or redraw all Rect you previous drew.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a duplicate question, I answered it before here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73561116/2615007

When creating RenderObjects from scratch it's easy to get carried away, but my advice is to not fear repainting. When you call methods on a canvas all it's doing is adding commands to a list that eventually get sent to the raster thread, no actual rendering work is being done here.

It sounds like you are confused on the purpose of `canvas.save` and `canvas.restore`. These methods do not save what you painted to the canvas, they only touch the paint transform set by scale, skew, transform and translate.